# PHP error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE on setting feature image in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to make my feature image (hero image) on WordPress to be dynamic (depends on the page). I have the following code to do it.

```
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check for feature image ?>

    <section class="feature-image" style="background: url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>') no-repeat; background-size: cover;" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

    <?php } elseif ( is_page('faqs') ) { // fallback image ?>

    <section class="feature-image feature-image-faqs" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php else { // fallback image ?>

    <section class="feature-image feature-image-default" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

    <?php } ?>
```

However, an error is prompted on this line:

```
<?php else { // fallback image ?>
```

The error goes like this:

```
 syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `<?php } ?>  <?php else { // fallback image ?>` - If you keep that `else` inside same `<?php ?>` it should work. But I dont know the reason behind it

Comment: Thank you so much @SougataBose! It worked!

Comment: Most probably `?>` is termination that control structure and thus the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed an error in your PHP.

**Corrected code:**

```
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check for feature image ?>

    <section class="feature-image" style="background: url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>') no-repeat; background-size: cover;" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

<?php } elseif ( is_page('faqs') ) { // fallback image ?>

    <section class="feature-image feature-image-faqs" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

<?php } else { // fallback image ?>

    <section class="feature-image feature-image-default" data-type="background" data-speed="2">
        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </section>

<?php } ?>
```